# Need help to determine if load bearing wall and or how to fix

Tags: repair, walls, load-bearing, water-damage, rot

[![enter image description here][image][2]][2]I am remodeling my upstairs bathroom and removed the shower pan and floor was rotted. The plywood extends under the wall into my bedroom. My question is how can I remove the rest of the wood under the wall to replace with new, also part of the corner wall. I put a few pictures to show the attic location as well, my bedroom is vaulted then drops down into the bathroom.

[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXYro.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXYro.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGhyD.jpg)[image][image][image][image]

Comment: If the wall runs parallel to the floor joists it *probably* isn't load bearing.

Comment: The picture that shows the attic, is showing where the vaulted ceiling in bedroom is going down to rest of ceiling exactly where the wall would be, so the joists are running straight across over the wall.

Comment: You should consult an engineer when working on a major portion of the in-house walls.

Comment: I would if I knew one, I don’t have the extra money to hire one, so that is why I am looking for a little guidance. I just want to be able to lay a new sheet under the damaged section for now to give me piece of mind as it is currently all damaged and half rotted out under the wall.